# HttpUrlConnection: multipart request POST

Tags: android, multipartform-data, httpurlconnection

I'm using multipart request in my app to send multiple files + some parameters to server. It worked with previous backend lib (express-formidable) but it is no longer working with current lib(Multer).

Backend dev said that he received empty request body so I received `400 - Bad Request` as response.

Is there anything that needs to be changed in order to make it pass successfully for Multer?

Here is entire multipart request:

```
fun apiMultipart(): ApiResult {
    val url = URL(apiUrl)
    boundary = getBoundary()

    try {

        val connnection = createConnection(ApiMethod.POST.method, url)

        val requestStream = DataOutputStream(connnection.outputStream)
        formFieldData.data.forEach { ffd->
            addFormField(ffd.first, ffd.second?:"null", requestStream)
        }
        addBitmapData(data, requestStream)
        addEnd(requestStream)
        requestStream.flush()

        return getResponse(connnection)
    }catch (e: IOException){
        //return error - exception
    }
}

fun getResponse(con: HttpURLConnection): ApiResult{
    //handle response
}

private const val LINE_FEED = "\r\n"
private fun getBoundary(): String{
    return "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "==="
}

private fun createConnection(method: String, url: URL): HttpURLConnection{
    with(url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection){
        requestMethod = method
        setRequestProperty(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data;boundary=$boundary")
        addRequestProperty(HEADER_API_KEY, apiDef.apiKey)
        session?.let { addRequestProperty(HEADER_SESSION, it) }
        setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*")
        setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive")
        setRequestProperty("cache-control", "no-cache")
        doOutput = true

        return this
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a form field to the request
 *
 * @param name  field name
 * @param value field value
 * @param outputStream data stream
 */
fun addFormField(name: String, value: Any, outputStream: DataOutputStream) {
    App.log("addFormFieldData: name: $name, value: $value")
    outputStream.apply {
        writeBytes("--$boundary$LINE_FEED")
        writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;$LINE_FEED")
        writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$name\"$LINE_FEED$LINE_FEED")

        if (value is String){
            write(value.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        } else {
            writeBytes("$value")
        }
        writeBytes(LINE_FEED)
    }
}

fun addEnd(outputStream: DataOutputStream){
    outputStream.apply {
        writeBytes(LINE_FEED)
        writeBytes("--$boundary$LINE_FEED")
    }
}

fun addFileEnd(outputStream: DataOutputStream){
    outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED)
}

fun addBitmapData(bmapsData: List<BitmapImageData>, outputStream: DataOutputStream){
    bmapsData.forEach { bmData ->
        addFileHeader(bmData.name, bmData.name, "image/jpeg", outputStream)
        bmData.bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, outputStream)
        addFileEnd(outputStream)
    }
}

fun addFileHeader(name: String, filename: String, contentType: String, outputStream: DataOutputStream){
    outputStream.apply {
        writeBytes("--$boundary$LINE_FEED")
        writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$name\"; filename=\"./$filename\"$LINE_FEED")
        writeBytes("Content-Type: $contentType$LINE_FEED$LINE_FEED")
    }
}
```